# Error: The drivers for this device are not installed (Code 28). Unable to connect Nikon D7200 to PC?

Tags: nikon, usb

I recently installed Windows 10 and I am unable to connect my Nikon D7200 to the PC. I was able to connect the same with Windows 8. How can I get the camera to connect using WIndows 10?

Comment: What have you tried? What error messages did you get? "It doesn't work" isn't a question we can really help with.

Comment: As such there is no error. I just connected and nothing pops up, When i checked the device manager, I noticed that " The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)"

Comment: Have you installed all the required Nikon software/drivers? If not, why not?

Comment: I installed all the required stuff. Even contact Microsoft support as well. Issue is pending into their kitty too.

Comment: This might be a problem with specific USB controller but I cannot tell any more.

Answer (score 1):

Call nikon customer support they are very helpful with problems lime yours They are based in the US so communicating is not an issue. The number is 800-nikon-us.   800-645-6687.